# Pandas DataFrame transforming with hugginface dataset

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, huggingface-datasets

```
from datasets import ClassLabel, Sequence
import random
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display, HTML

def show_random_elements(dataset, num_examples=10):
    assert num_examples <= len(dataset), "Can't pick more elements than there are in the dataset."
    picks = []
    for _ in range(num_examples):
        pick = random.randint(0, len(dataset)-1)
        while pick in picks:
            pick = random.randint(0, len(dataset)-1)
        picks.append(pick)

    df = pd.DataFrame(dataset[picks])
    for column, typ in dataset.features.items():
        if isinstance(typ, ClassLabel):          
            df[column] = df[column].transform(lambda i: typ.names[i])
        elif isinstance(typ, Sequence) and isinstance(typ.feature, ClassLabel):
            df[column] = df[column].transform(lambda x: [typ.feature.names[i] for i in x])
    display(HTML(df.to_html()))
```

The code above is the function that show some examples picked randomly in the HuggingFace dataset.

I have two questions from above.

1. `(lambda i: typ.names[i])`

I can't understand what this lambda function exactly do.

2. Similar to first question, why transforming `df[column]` is needed?

As I put `print(df[column])` both before and after line `df[column] = df[column].transform(lambda i: typ.names[i])`, I saw there is nothing changed.

Thanks.